# Firestore data structuring for building owners

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, database-design

I am currently a high school student and I'm working on a Java, Android Studio project that involves creating an app using a database. I chose to go with Firestore.

My app is going to be an app that will store data about some buildings in my city. The building owners will create an account and they will be able to upload data about their buildings. My question is, how do I do that in the database? I've already done the auth process and the users are automatically stored in a collection. Now, I'd like some suggestions about how the user can assign himself the building he owns, and how can i structure this data to be able to assign the building to a user which will be able to upload or modify data about the building. I'd also like to split the buildings into districts, and each district shall have a supervisor who will receive all the data the building owners upload. I'm new to working with databases and I really want to expand my knowledge in this area.

I haven't really tried anything yet since I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My app is going to be an app that will store data about some buildings in my city. The building owners will create an account and they will be able to upload data about their buildings. My question is, how do I do that in the database?

The most appropriate solution would be to create a top-level collection called "users" and a sub-collection under each user document called "buildings".

> Now, I'd like some suggestions about how the user can assign himself the building he owns, and how can I structure this data to be able to assign the building to a user who will be able to upload or modify data about the building.

Since you're using authentication, you already know the UID of the authenticated user. That being said when the user wants to add a new building (document) to the "buildings" sub-collection, then create a reference that points to the "buildings" sub-collection:

```
db/users/$uid/buildings
```

And then call [CollectionReference#add()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference#add(java.lang.Object)). To let the user modify a building, simply create a reference that points to the building the user wants to modify and let him change whatever data he wants using [DocumentReference#update()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference#update(java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,java.lang.Object%3E)). The path is:

```
db/users/$uid/buildings/$buildingId
```

> I'd also like to split the buildings into districts, and each district shall have a supervisor who will receive all the data the building owners upload.

In this case, you should create another top-level collection called "districts" where you can add district documents. Each district document should contain a field called "supervisor" that will contain the UID of the supervisor. Besides that, each building document should also contain a field called "districtId". In this way, you'll be able to display all buildings within a specific district using a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).

If you would like to query the building documents under a certain path, I recommend reading the following resource:

- [How to query collections in Firestore under a certain path?](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-query-collections-in-firestore-under-a-certain-path-6a0d686cebd2)

To wire up all this information, please check the schema below:

```
db
|
--- users (collection)
|    |
|    --- $uid (document)
|         |
|         --- type: "owner" //Can be owner or supervisor.
|         |
|         --- //other user fields
|         |
|         ---  buildings: (sub-collection)
|               |
|               --- $buildingId (document)
|                    |
|                    --- districtId: "DistrictLongId"
|                    |
|                    --- //other building details
|
--- districts (collection)
     |
     --- $districId (document)
           |
           --- name: "DistrictName"
           |
           --- supervisor: "SupervisorLongId"
           |
           --- //other distric details
```

Comment: "And then call CollectionReference#add(). To let the user modify a building, simply create a reference that points to the building the user wants to modify and let him change whatever data he wants using DocumentReference#update(). The path is: " That seems like a great ideea, but i don't want the users to able to create new buildinigs. I'd like the users to assign themselves pre-existing buildings that I, the app administrator, will upload to the database.

Comment: Then don't allow the user to create buildings, let only the admin do that. Then display a list of buildings and let the users assign themselves the buildings that already exist in the database.